# Axios making 2 requests on refresh

Tags: reactjs

When I navigate using Link (react router-dom) I don't have this problem, but if I refresh the browser I get a 403 error in console saying unauthorised and then I get the data in the next request with a 200 response. Why is this making what looks like 2 requests when refreshing the browser?

```
import { AuthContext } from "../../shared/context/auth-context";

const ContactEntries = () => {
const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    const source = Axios.CancelToken.source();
    setIsLoading(true);

    const getContactEnquiries = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await Axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/v1/contact`,
          {
            cancelToken: source.token,
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token },
          }
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setEnquiries(response.data.enquiries);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(err.response);
      }
    };

    getContactEnquiries();
    return () => {
      source.cancel();
    };
  }, [!!auth.token]);
}
```

Here is my authContext:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  userId: null,
  token: null,
  email: null,
  firstName: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});
```

Comment: @ggorlen, supposed to be a short way to check if auth.token is truthy. But if I replace it with just `[auth.token`] I still have the same issue. So I guess it is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your useEffect is running twice on refresh. On first render it is not getting auth.token and may be it null. And on second render it is making call with 200 status code.

You have to check auth token it coming successfully.

You can check it this way

```
useEffect(() => {
    const source = Axios.CancelToken.source();
    setIsLoading(true);

    const getContactEnquiries = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await Axios.get(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/v1/contact`,
          {
            cancelToken: source.token,
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token },
          }
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
          setIsLoading(false);
          setEnquiries(response.data.enquiries);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(err.response);
      }
    };
    if(auth.token) getContactEnquiries();
    return () => {
      source.cancel();
    };
  }, [!!auth.token]);
```